# How to optimize Impala query to combine LIKE with IN (literally or effectively)?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sql-like, impala

I need to try and optimize a query in Impala SQL that does partial string matches on about 60 different strings, against two columns in a database of 50+ billion rows. The values in these two columns are encrypted and have to be decrypted with a user defined function (in Java) to do the partial string match. So query would look something like:

```
SELECT decrypt_function(column_A), decrypt_function(column_B) FROM myTable WHERE ((decrypt_function(column_A) LIKE '%' + partial_string_1 + '%') OR (decrypt_function(column_B) LIKE '%' + partial_string_1 + '%')) OR ((decrypt_function(column_A) LIKE '%' + partial_string_2 + '%') OR (decrypt_function(column_B) LIKE '%' + partial_string_2 + '%')) OR ... [up to partial_string_60]
```

What I really want to do is decrypt the two column values I'm comparing with, once for each row and then compare that value with all the partial strings, then go onto the next row etc (for 55 billion rows). Is that possible somehow? Can there be a subquery that assigns the decrypted column value to a variable before using that to do the string comparison to each of the 60 strings? Then go onto the next row...

Or is some other optimization possible? E.g. using 'IN', so `...  WHERE (decrypt_function(column_A) IN ('%' + partial_string_1 + '%', '%' + partial_string_2 + '%', ... , '%' + partial_string_60 + '%')) OR (decrypt_function(column_B) IN ('%' + partial_string_1 + '%', '%' + partial_string_2 + '%', ... , '%' + partial_string_60 + '%'))`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery and also regexp_like can have many patterns concatenated with OR (`|`), so you can check all alternatives in single regexp, though you may need to split into several function calls if the pattern string is too long:

```
select colA, ColB 
from
(--decrypt in the subquery
SELECT decrypt_function(column_A) as colA, decrypt_function(column_B) as ColB 
  FROM myTable 
) as s
where 
--put most frequent substrings first in the regexp 
regexp_like(ColA,'partial_string_1|partial_string_2|partial_string_3') --add more
OR         
regexp_like(ColB,'partial_string_1|partial_string_2|partial_string_3')
```

In Hive use this syntax:

```
where ColA rlike 'partial_string_1|partial_string_2|partial_string_3'
   OR ColB rlike 'partial_string_1|partial_string_2|partial_string_3'
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. So looks as if I don't need to specify the % sign when using the partial strings (as I do with LIKE) ?

Comment: @AlexKerr You do not need %. regexp syntax is different and can be much more complex. If you want to use complex regular expressions, study regexp, see https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html